# UITableView Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have got a UITableView in my ViewController and it's row has custom content. Every cell's height dynamically calculated according to cell's content with `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

But how can set UITableView's height?
Because if my table contains only one row, after row i see a big whitespace in my table?
Isn't there any property to set table's height dynamically increase or reduce according to its contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `contentSize` will be adjusted as needed by the number of rows and sections you have, if you want to change the actual size of the table view you should adjust the `frame` property

you might just be better off putting a backgroundView or colour on the table if its that the white background when you only have a few rows is bothering you

Comment: ok; but how can i determine how much i need to increase height? because, every row's height is different and i don't know the exact value.

Comment: the contentSize should be updated for you automatically, check that, and if it is less than the frame size you can adjust

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand contentSize thing. how can i check was it updated automatically? also i couldn't use background because there is a button below tableview; so i put a background there will be a big gap between button and tableview. actually it is another problem for me, there isn't any way to position controls relatively.

Comment: if you want the button to be at the bottom of the table, add it to the table's footerView. The contentSize is a UIScrollView property which is updated by the table as cells are added, you would need to check after the content has been set up (or do the calculation yourself since you know the number of cells and their height)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to look details for contentSize of tableView. I am using it with UİScrollView but i had never used it for tableView

Answer (score 1):

Try the contentSize method, which is inherited from UITableView’s superclass, UIScrollView. However, you may find that contentSize returns an incorrect or out of date value, so you should probably call layoutIfNeeded first to recalculate the table’s layout.

```
[tableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

// Allows you to perform layout before the drawing cycle happens. //-layoutIfNeeded forces layout early. So it will correctly return the size. Like dreaming before doing.

```
CGSize tableSize=tableView.contentSize;
```